# How to run a WHMCS hook for any one template

Tags: php, whmcs

I want to run a hook only one template? I mean the primary navigation bar hook should be run if anyone access the WHMCS by using `index.php?systpl=six` Not on any other template.

Thanks.

Comment: This has been close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, WHMCS developer documentation doesn't provide a way to get the current template for menus hooks.

But I noticed that there is a global variable that have the active template, you need to test through all pages to make sure code is working, I tested on Client Services page:

```
function my_custom_navs_func() {

    global $inputParams;

    $activeTemplate = $inputParams['clientareatemplate'];

    if ($activeTemplate == 'six') {

        //Do something here!
    }
}
add_hook('ClientAreaNavbars', 1, 'my_custom_navs_func');
```